# Запуск программы Node.js из командной строки без указания node

Tags: javascript, node.js, alasql

Разрабатывается пакет для Node.js, в котором есть утилита для работы из командной строки. Сейчас [alacon.js](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/blob/master/alacon.js) представляет собой JavaScript программу, размещенную в корне пакета. Для запуска этой утилиты приходится вводить слово **node** перед названием утилиты, например:

```
node alacon 'SELECT * FROM CSV("mydata.csv") ORDER BY 2'
```

Что нужно настроить в package.json, какие файлы надо создать и как сделать так, чтобы:

1.Для запуска этой утилиты не нужно было указывать слово **node**:

```
alacon 'SELECT 1+1'
```

2.Можно было бы установить пакет глобально и использовать утилиту:

```
npm install -g alasql
```

То есть, сделать так же, как это сделано в Jison, Gulp и многих других Node.js пакетах с утилитами?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как правильно указали DAiMor и novus42, надо сделать ДВЕ вещи:

**package.json**

```
{ "bin" : { "alacon" : "./bin/alacon.js" } }
```

**alacon.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

при выполнении `npm install -g alasql` бинарник ставится в директорию доступную через PATH.

При этом номерация параметров не изменится. Нулевой будет node(.exe) а первый `alacon.js`.

Comment: Я сделал все, как Вы написали, система инсталлирует ```npm install -g alasql```, потом выдает сообщение, что создает для этих файлов что-то в каталоге /usr/local/bin. Но после запуска дает сообщение '-L: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory'. У меня OSX. Не встречались с такой проблемой?

Comment: Не понятно как запускаете, `/usr/local/bin/alacon.js` Попробуйте. И убедитесь что первая строка вашей js программы находит ноду.

Comment: Разобрались, причина была в том, что нужно было заменить CRLF на LF в тексте alacon.js. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

Документация по npm [говорит](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin), что для этого в package.json нужно добавить

```
{ "bin" : { "alacon" : "./bin/alacon.js" } }
```

Answer (score 3):

Cтандартный способ в Юниксах это прописать первой строкой:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Потом сделать:

```
chmod +x <scriptname>
```

И запускать соответственно:

```
./scriptname
```